# Does the name of an addressee's house need to go in inverted commas on the envelope?

Tags: punctuation

If someone lives at a house called 'Dunroamin' or 'Rose Cottage', or 'The Pig Sty', do you put it in inverted commas in the address on the envelope? e.g. do I write:

> Mr & Mrs J. Percival,
>   'The Shambles',
>   Bedrock Rd,
>   Little Snoring,
>   postcode.

Or do I write:

> Mr & Mrs J. Percival,
>   The Shambles,
>   Bedrock Rd etc.?

Answer (score 1):

No quotes (single or double) are used in the US.

Comment: I'm sure that's the case here too. But I do receive mail from people who put their house-name in quotes.

Comment: @WS2 Unless you're withholding vital information (like 'all these letters are from Australia'), there is a logical impossibility in your two sentences. Grammar-Monster says [You can use quotation marks for the names of books, plays, films, articles, ships, aircraft, houses and hotels. (You do not have to though.)](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/quotation_(speech)_marks_ships_plays_books.htm) whereas [The Oxford Guide to Style](http://www.eng-lang.co.uk/ogs.htm) recommends you don't.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth point taken. I'm sure that's the rule here too, but some people who send me mail put their house-name in quotes.

Comment: @WS2 But I've just pointed out there **isn't** a rule.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  Well for 'rule' read 'best practice'. Or should it be 'better practice'?.

Comment: @WS2 I put it in quotes. I think that's better. Probably most anglophones don't any more. However, I'd have to look up the 'rules' for albums and titles – I think there are actually _rules_ here, laid down by the music industry, which one chooses to go against at one's financial peril.

Comment: I wouldn't put it in quotes. A house name is a name as a city name is a name as a place name is a name. If The Shambles is in quotes, then should Manchester also? The Shambles, by the way, is the name of a street in York. Should that be in quotes? Should Bedrock Rd?

Comment: The USPS prefers you [not use any punctuation at all](http://pe.usps.gov/cpim/ftp/pubs/pub28/pub28.pdf).